# How to create three bottom tabs with middle tab width twice of others 2 in android?

Tags: android

I want to create three bottom tabs with middle tab of different width in which on clicking a tab it opens a screen above them using fragment.
ps: can I achieve this without bottom navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

You have to write your select/deselect logic for each tab view

**pseudo code**

```
<RelativeLayout>
.
.
.
.
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I already knows the weight logic but the thing is how can I achieve the onClick a tab to open another screen in upper part using fragments

Comment: Add framelayout above linearlayout set onClickListener to each textviews and just replace the fragment in framelayout

Comment: yeah, its working fine with frameLayout for onClick functionality for those three Tab!